# Extrude problem blender

Tags: modeling

Hi I am a newbie to blender. I am trying to model a M4 Sherman tank but I cant get through this problem. I am trying to extrude the part above the wheelbase. But I only manage to do this with a rectangle that causes with problems with loopcuts later in the program. Does anyone know a method for extrusion where the mesh still is one mesh and where I can still loopcut around the meshes to get a nice joint? I highlighted the square that prevents me for doing a proper loopcut.

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to see the forms from the drawings alone and Google search returns few different variations of the M4 model. I would advice to do more research and find photographs of the one you wish to model so you understand the forms better. This is the single best advice I can ever give - find more reference data, as much as you can, so you can see the forms in your mind. Then it makes sense to model it in a similar way it is actually made - it is not a single volume, but instead a lot of different parts. Those parts would probably be modelled separately by an experienced modeler. They would require different modelling techniques as well.

[image]

(source: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:M4_Sherman_tank_Battling_Annie.jpg)

If you have a closer look it seems as if this one in the image above was made from separate sheets of metal welded or bolted together as well as some cast metal parts. It might be easier to model those sheets and parts separately, place them into correct positions in space matching the blueprints and then join them instead of trying to extrude everything. I would try to imagine how it was manufactured and follow that logic when modeling.

Comment: Thanks Martynas, for the detailled information. I think it is very helpful! The problem I am facing is with the casted hull variant of the tank, see link below (I dont know how to upload photo's yet like you did in the comments). The reason I thought I needed to get a loopcut around that part is because I want the edge not te be fully sharp and I want to use the subdivision modifier to get to this. 

[link](https://www.reddit.com/r/TankPorn/comments/rw3sx1/i_really_like_the_early_cast_hull_shermans/)

Comment: It may be the case that I get the proces totally wrong. Maybe I just have to make the separate objects like you said and then just use bevel on the objects after I join them.

Comment: Hard to advice. It's not single operation like extrude or bevel that you need, but all modelling tools. I would  model this in separate parts as in reality, but also it might be helpful to construct the organic form out of simpler forms, joining them together. This is getting to sound purely opinion based now(so not really BSE thing). The fact is that you do need to understand the forms you are attempting to model, so you do need to have plenty of clear photographs of the thing from all sides, not just the drawings and also dividing a complex thing into simpler ones does help.